# Undefined index and cannot modify header info debug

Tags: php, wordpress

I get this after wp_debug has been switched

```
Notice: Undefined index: enabled in /home/bhrmwgng/public_html/metasyfe.com/wp-content/plugins/above-the-fold-optimization/includes/localizejs.class.php on line 123

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/bhrmwgng/public_html/metasyfe.com/wp-content/plugins/above-the-fold-optimization/includes/localizejs.class.php:123) in /home/bhrmwgng/public_html/metasyfe.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1207
```

Comment: Or / and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php/8028987#8028987

Answer (score 0):

Starting with WordPress version 2.5, setting [WP_DEBUG](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) to true also raises the error reporting level to E_ALL and activates warnings when deprecated functions or files are used; otherwise, WordPress sets the error reporting level to E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_USER_NOTICE.

This cause this messages that are not errors, are **Notice** and **Warning** levels to be shown.

See: http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php